# How to use a function as a parameter of a function?

Tags: python, function, parameters

Say I have a function `sum(x,y)` which returns `x+y`. Another function `adder(s,...)` which takes `s` as a parameter.

I want to find the number of parameters of `s` in adder:

```
import inspect
adder(s):
     x = inspect.getargspecs(s)  # no of parameter is `s`
     print x
```

I get the error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'getargspecs'
```

What's wrong? How do I get the number of parameters of `s` in `adder()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called [`.getargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), not `.getargspecs()`:

```
import inspect

def adder(s):
    x = inspect.getargspec(s) #no of parameter is s
    print(x)

adder(sum)
```

Note that the method was *deprecated in Python 3.0* in favor of [`.signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) method.

Comment: Well, then I'd say  vote to close this question as **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error** instead of answer it.

Comment: @KevinGuan second close vote is mine. Good point though in general. Just wanted to add some detail.